# Remove All Strings From Array, But Keep Strings With Specific Length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make Wordle in React. For that I need a list of Strings. I am getting an array of strings from this API: https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/all

The problem is that I don't want every word. I only want words that has a length of 5. How do I remove all the strings that doesn't have a length of 5 from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of words, `words`, [use `Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const fiveLetterWords = words.filter(w => w.length === 5)
```